# Django Static Files not syncing image

Tags: html, django, python-2.7

I couldn't get my image reflected using StaticFile process. Here are my global settings:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
   ('assets', 'C:/Users/dhopkins/PycharmProjects/django_test/static'),
```

My base.html:

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <title>{% block title %}My base template.{% endblock %}</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "assets/css/default.css" %}">
</head>

<body>
<div id="page">

</div>
<div id="sidebar">
    {% block sidebar %}
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/articles/all">Articles</a></li>
        <li><a href="/admin/">Admin</a></li>
    </ul>
    {% endblock %}
</div>
<div id="content">
    {% block content %}Content goes here!{% endblock %}
    <img scr="{% static "images/python-logo.jpg" %}" width="200"/>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

My image folder is located in C:\Users\dhopkins\PycharmProjects\django_test\static\images.
Please help.

Comment: Maybe problem is in prefix 'assets'? Can you try to remove it?

Comment: By removing 'assets' its not detecting css as well. Css settings doesn't reflect on template by removing it at all.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem lies in this line

```
 <img scr="{% static "images/python-logo.jpg" %}" width="200"/>
```

it should be

```
 <img src="{% static "images/python-logo.jpg" %}" width="200"/>
```

This is not a problem with your static files. You've simply misspelled the `<img src>` attribute  :-)